# On click Angular function won't work

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I want to launch a new page when a cube is clicked using Angular. My code is currently not doing anything when I click the boxes so I might have everything wrong.

My on-click function is:

```
$scope.clicked = function(){
      console.log('pppp');
       window.location = "#/test.html";
 }
```

I call the function in my HTML like this:

```
<html>
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Bungee+Hairline" rel="stylesheet">


<header>
  Angularity
</header>

<body ng-app="App">
<div ng-click="clicked()" class="wrap">
    <div class="cube" change-background colorcode=¨#f45642¨>
        <div class="front" ><span>E</span></div>
        <div class="back" ></div>
        <div class="top" ></div>
        <div class="bottom" ></div>
        <div class="left" ></div>
        <div class="right" ></div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="wrap2">
    <div class="cube" change-background>
      <div class="front"  colorcode=¨#f45642¨><span>S</span></div>
        <div class="back"></div>
        <div class="top"></div>
        <div class="bottom"></div>
        <div class="left"></div>
        <div class="right"></div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="wrap3">
    <div class="cube" change-background>
      <div class="front"  colorcode=¨#f45642¨><span>C</span></div>
        <div class="back"></div>
        <div class="top"></div>
        <div class="bottom"></div>
        <div class="left"></div>
        <div class="right"></div>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

What is wrong with my code that is not allowing a new link to launch when a box is clicked?

http://codepen.io/Feners4/pen/KggAwg

Comment: you set $scope.clicked after the return statement.  You also look like that even it was before the return, that $scope is not really defined in that outer function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a fixed version. The problem in your original code pen was that the div element was outside your directive. You also defined `$scope.clicked` in the wrong spot. I've created a new directive myClick, so it now the HTML looks like

```
<div ng-click="clicked()" my-click class="wrap">
    <div class="cube" change-background colorcode="#f45642">
    </div>
</div>
```

And the directive definition is here:

```
angular.module('App', [])
  .directive('changeBackground', () => {...})
  .directive('myClick', () => {
    return { 
      restrict: 'A',
      link: (scope) => {
        scope.clicked = () => {
          console.log('pppp');
          window.location = "#/test.html";
        }
      }
    };
});
```

http://codepen.io/phillypham/pen/PbgXOE

Answer (score 1):

You need to define the ng-controller and define the clicked function there.

```
<body ng-app="App">
    <div ng-controller="TestCtrl">
         .....
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to create a new controller and you want just to redirect the user to that url, you can add the click event on your directive:

```
link: function($scope, element, attr) {
   element.on('click', function() { window.location = "#/test.html"; });
   [omissis]
enter code here
```